# How to get the link that the user tried to visit, from a 404 custom page made in php

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, multilingual

I have a website in different languages, thus I want to show a custom 404 page for each language.

Is there a way to find out which page the user tried to visit (that didn't exist) in order to find out which language I should display the 404 page?

The web server is Apache.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you use any framework?

Comment: No, I don't. It's all php files.

Comment: Then you probably need to explain how you know which language to use for pages that exist.

Comment: it's by the links, all english pages are like 'www.mysite.com/en/intro.php" , french ones are "www.mysite.com/fr/intro.php', etc. Ajay has answered me, so I have the answer now, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `.htaccess` file for redirect then add

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourdir/error/404page.php
```

then use request uri in session which stores the page user are visiting i.e.

```
$_SESSION['req_uri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then redirect user to `$_SESSION['req_uri']`.
where `$_SESSION['req_uri']` is the page user trying to access.

Comment: What I'm asking is how can the "404page.php" know which link the user tried to visit?